# listbox selecteditems cannot be removed due to using ItemsSource

Tags: c#, listbox, selecteditem

I need you to help fix my issues. When I use listbox ItemSource in my code, selected items cannot be allowed to remove. Without using ListBox ItemsSource, the remove operation is working. Why? Please give me your soultion code. I need to include ItemsSource for the listbox. Thanks a million times! Oh yes I am using C# 4.5 and WPF.

```
    public SendEmail(List<string> items, ItemCollection needsItems)
    : this()
    {
        _needList = needsItems;

        lstNeeds.ItemsSource = _needList;
    }

  //Remove selected Items not working

 if (lstNeeds.SelectedItem != null)
    {

      for (int i = lstNeeds.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
       {
         lstNeeds.Items.Remove(lstNeeds.SelectedItems[i]);
       }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @PoweredByOrange it is "Dark" theme I think, to set that go to Tools->Options->Environment->General in right side there is list(Color theme combobox) of themes select "Dark" one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to remove an item from the collection you're iterating over.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (lstNeeds.SelectedItem != null)
{
    List<Int32> selIdx = new List<Int32>();
    foreach (var item in lstNeeds.SelectedItems)
        selIdx.Add(lstNeeds.Items.IndexOf(item);
    selIdx.Sort();  //necessary?
    for (Int32 idx = selIdx.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        lstNeeds.Items.RemoveAt(selIdx[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: SelectedIndices doesnt exist in IntelliSense.

Comment: I see that you are correct (I don't use WPF much, sorry).  Edited.

Comment: Thanks for editing but your code is not working as I got error message : Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

Comment: Have a look at the picture on my post (above)